# Docusaurus - How to remove TOC(table of contents)?

Tags: docusaurus

I'm using [docusaurus](https://docusaurus.io/) for our dev docs.

How to disable TOC?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Docosaurus has [Markdown Frontmatter](https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/plugins/@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs#markdown-frontmatter) metadata fields for `.md` files where you will eventually make use of the [`hide_table_of_contents`](https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/plugins/@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs#:%7E:text=hide_table_of_contents%3A%20whether%20to%20hide%20the%20table%20of%20contents%20to%20the%20right.%20default%20value%3A%20false) field and set it to `true`.

Your `.md` should look like:

```
--- 
hide_table_of_contents: true
---
# Markdown Features
My Document Markdown content
```

Answer (score 3):

There does not seem to be a way to make the `hide_table_of_contents` setting default to `true`; you need to add it to the Front Matter for every document if you want to completely disable the ToC display.

Another approach to completely disable the ToC display would be to edit the css, adding:

```
.theme-doc-toc-desktop {
   display: none;
}
```